# can I replace the <ul> tag with other element

Tags: html, tags, html-lists

I have a bit of code that looks like

```
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="Pages/logout8.html">Login</a></li>
          </ul>
```

that makes an element that looks like

[image]

Is there anyway I can remove the underline. I've tried switching the ul tag to  but that didn't work.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add in CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

To disable all text-decorations like underline.

Answer (score 1):

Try this css:

```
.dropdown-menu li a:link {text-decoration:none;}
```

If you want to remove underline completely use following:

```
.dropdown-menu li a:link {text-decoration:none;}
.dropdown-menu li a:visited {text-decoration:none;}
.dropdown-menu li a:hover {text-decoration:underline;}
.dropdown-menu li a:active {text-decoration:underline;}
```

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/ZaeG5/)

Answer (score 1):

The underline isn't really caused by the `<ul>` tag but by the link. `<ul>` is basically just a container for lists ([ul = unordered list](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp)).

To remove the underline from your text you will have to use CSS (or javascript but CSS is faster).

just add the following to your CSS:

```
.dropdown-menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

This will remove all decorations of your link.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving `text-direction:none` to the `a` tag

More info on [Text Decoration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration)

Answer (score 0):

The `text-decoration : underline` is the default style for `a[href]` element. So if the href attribute of a  tag is set, underline will appear on its text.

To remove that default behavior :

```
.dropdown-menu li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```